# Function overload with conditional return type is broken when enclosing type is a part of a union

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-statements

Consider this example:

```js
interface Foo<T> {
   bar<TKey>(arg: TKey) : TKey extends T ? 1 : 2;
   bar(): void; // try commenting this line
}

const x: Foo<'a' | 'b'> | Foo<'a'> = undefined as any;

const r1 = x.bar('a' as const); // 1
const r2 = x.bar('b' as const); // 1 | 2
const r3 = x.bar('c' as const); // 2
```

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqA+ZAbwChkyAjOKXAaQgE88AKKgcwC5kc76BKZTtwbIIAD0ggAJgGcuyAPzIAjAOQAmANykKVJr04A3dMEkbkAenPIwUesgToAto4jhQrawAtgsgDagIYgBfYmIHEGkwZFFODGwAcjh45AAfZHjyeII0uKxErOQAXmQAVykIGADJZDhZOBB6LTD0CKioFWLRADpKKCZ8mtlwyN4zS2Vm1uQoNSLont0M5Nr7FpGxqxU0tUnI6YBmOe7e-oRlobWwUYsrHeIgA))

Compilation fails with message `'Expected 0 arguments, but got 1'` thought there is an overload for this case.
If parameterless overload is removed, everything works fine, return type is determined correctly.

Why adding parameterless overload breaks another one, accepting a parameter?

Comment: The type of `x.bar` is quite complicated, a union of overloaded generic functions. Support for calling unions exists of functions as of TS3.3 but there are [caveats](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#caveats) from [ms/TS#29011](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011) and you're ticking all the boxes here.  A union of functions is conceptually the same as a function of intersections of arguments, but figuring out how to unify overloads and generics is nontrivial.  Does that answer your question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz - Is it the conditional type that makes it a union of overloaded generic functions?

Comment: No, but the fact that the return type depends on `T` means that the call signatures are not identical and need to be unified.  We could rewrite these without conditional types and reproduce the issue (but I’m on mobile now so I can’t demo easily)

Comment: [Here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/mxBQZw) where there are no conditional types involved but the same error occurs.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for those links!
I understand the problem background well enough now